# Cannot add fields to embed after declaring

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a help command for my bot, I tried

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    var Discord = require("discord.js");
    const fs = require('fs');
      // Help command
      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Help")
      .setDescription("Availible commands are listed here")
      fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        files.forEach(file => {
          if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
          let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
          embed.addField(commandName)
        });
      });
      message.channel.send(embed)
  };
```

But nothing is added to the embed, and I don't get any errors.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Discord documentation for [MessageEmbed#addField](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField), the fields `name` and `value` are **required**, the field for `inline` is optional.

In your code you're only passing one parameter which is not enough for it to work. Also make sure `commandName` is truly a string and not something undefined or null. So instead try this:

```js
embed.addField(commandName, 'This the command description');
```

The maximum fields you can add is `25`. After 25 fields, it will stop adding more fields.

Beside that, you are trying to send an embed which is getting fields assigned within an async function. Try to move the `message.channel.send()` function up within the `readdir()` function, something like this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');
// Help command
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("Help").setDescription("Availible commands are listed here");
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
        let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
        embed.addField(commandName, `Description for ${commandName}`);
    });

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }); // Discord V13
});
```

if you are using Discord V12, you could use this for sending the message:

```
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: This sadly didn't work, it doesn't add the field to the embed and only sends the basic embed

Comment: @Zariaa_ I found the mistake, i've updated my answer. Now it should work :)